# Add a class to a dynamic sidebar's wrapper

Tags: plugin-development, widgets, sidebar

I am making a plugin to display featured pages of a site, but it depends on a flex container and i cannot assure that a user's sidebar is going to have a display of flex.

However, looking for solutions to my problem, i found a filter called dynamic_sidebar_params, which indeed allowed me to change the class of the desired sidebar, that is, the one(s) containing my plugin's widget. The problem is that this does not add a CSS class to the wrapper of the dynamic sidebar.

With the wrapper, i mean the element surrounding the dynamic_sidebar() function in the sidebar file. For instance:

sidebar-featured-pages.php

```
<?php
if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'featured-pages' ) )
{
    return;
} ?>

<section class="featured-pages">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'featured-pages' ) ?>
</section>
```

What i would like to do is modify or add a new class in that section element, or in whatever the user's sidebar wrapper happens to be.

This is what i tried:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package FeaturedPage
 */

namespace FeaturedPage\Custom;

class Extras
{
    /**
     * Register default hooks and actions for WordPress
     * @return
     */
    public function register()
    {
        add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', [ $this, 'add_sidebar_class' ] );
    }

    /**
     * Add a new CSS class to the sidebar containing the Featured Page widget(s)
     * @param array $parameters The sidebar parameters array
     * @return array $parameters The sidebar parameters array
     */
    public function add_sidebar_class( $parameters )
    {
        if ( preg_match( '/featured_page_widget-{0,}/', $parameters[0]['widget_id'] ) )
        {
            $parameters[0]['class'] = 'featured-pages-flex-container';
        }

        return $parameters;
    }
}
```

This does add a class to the sidebar. However, it is not a CSS class, it is the class added when registering a sidebar. But in [WordPress documentation it says](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/dynamic_sidebar_params/) about the class parameter: "CSS class applied to the sidebar container.".

How can i get the sidebar's wrapper? In this case, that section element with a class of featured-pages?

Answer (score 1):

What if the theme has other stuff added and/or styled their sidebar for all the other core widgets and only works with display:block for example, or they set it to flex column where you might expect flex row / vice versa.  I would suggest you add a wrapper to your widget content, if your widget content relies on a wrapper to be set a certain way, so you prevent breaking other widget's displays or display of the sidebar from theme to theme.  Afterall there's no guarantee there that they even set a wrapper around the sidebar call like is shown above.  You also don't have control over other plugins that might try to do this same thing - so then you would end up with incompatibility complaints.

Alternatively if you think this is really the best way to handle it for your particular situation, you could try using [dynamic_sidebar_before](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/dynamic_sidebar_before/) and [dynamic_sidebar_after](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/dynamic_sidebar_after/) hooks to add your own wrapper around  dynamic_sidebar calls.